# attribute being mandatory for tag JSP custom tag

Tags: java, jsp, custom-tags

im trying to create a custom tag that would check if the two strings are equal, the idea being later that i can mutate javabeans that i put into the tag.

```
package cknight.java3;


import javax.servlet.jsp.JspException;
import javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter;
import javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.*;

public class MyTagHandler extends TagSupport {
private String text ;
        private String convertedtext ;

    /**
     * @return the text
     */
    public String gettext() {
        return text;
    }

    /**
     * @param text the text to set
     */
    public void settext(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    /**
     * @return the convertedText
     */
    public String getconvertedText() {
        return convertedtext;
    }

    /**
     * @param convertedtext the convertedText to set
     */
    public void setconvertedText(String convertedtext) {
        this.convertedtext = convertedtext;
    }

@Override
    public int doStartTag() throws JspException {



        JspWriter out = pageContext.getOut();//returns the instance of JspWriter  

        try {

            if(text.equals(convertedtext))
            out.print("equal");
            else
            out.print("not equal");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
       return SKIP_BODY;//will not evaluate the body content of the tag  
    }
}
```

im not sure what is wrong, as im setting it in the tag. i keep getting error that there is no setter or that attribute is mandatory

```
<%-- 
    Document   : index
    Created on : May 1, 2016, 10:20:53 AM
    Author     : cknig
--%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<%@ taglib uri="WEB-INF/tlds/mytags.tld" prefix="m" %>


<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <p>this is where your custom tag would show up<m:tagExampleName text="example" contvertedText="example"/> <p>
    </body>
</html>
```

here is my tld file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<taglib version="2.1" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_1.xsd">
  <tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
  <short-name>mytags</short-name>
  <uri>/WEB-INF/tlds/mytags</uri>
  <!-- A validator verifies that the tags are used correctly at JSP
          translation time. Validator entries look like this: 
       <validator>
           <validator-class>com.mycompany.TagLibValidator</validator-class>
           <init-param>
              <param-name>parameter</param-name>
              <param-value>value</param-value>
           </init-param>
       </validator>
    -->
  <!-- A tag library can register Servlet Context event listeners in
         case it needs to react to such events. Listener entries look
         like this: 
      <listener>
          <listener-class>com.mycompany.TagLibListener</listener-class> 
      </listener>
    -->
    <tag>  
<name>tagExampleName</name>  
<tag-class>cknight.java3.MyTagHandler</tag-class>  
<attribute>
    <name>text</name>
    <required>true</required>
    <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
    <type> String </type>
    </attribute>
    <attribute>
    <name>contvertedtext</name>
    <required>true</required>
    <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
    <type> String </type>
    </attribute>
</tag>  
</taglib>
```

Comment: contvertedText != convertedtext : Aside from the misspelling, java is case sensitive. It is also best practice to use camelCase for variables and methods https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java

Comment: i know i changed the names becasue of this post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/224690/5310793)